WordPress "Polylang", wrong URL direction
Here's the problem:
I'm using the "Language Switcher" plugin by Polylang in WordPress, and I'm repeatedly being redirected to the wrong URL (website). I duplicated the main page and the menu tabs from the original English site (www.example.com) to the German version (www.example.com/de) using the "Yoast Duplicate Post" plugin.
Everything is working fine, including the menu and its tabs, except for the German main page (www.example.com/de).

It sounds like Polylang isn't linking the German page to the correct language. Go to the duplicated German page in WordPress, check the Languages section, and make sure it's set to German. If it's not, manually assign it and save. Clear your cache after that, and it should work.
